# Highchart - If there is no data the graph should display 0

Tags: php, graph, charts

Here is the problem!

On the left side is the chart, on the right the data. The data comes from an php-file. There is no data after 2013-01-18 13:00:00 .... there is a long break but then it starts at 2013-1-22 12:32:24 ... but between this dates I want that the graph runs at zero!

Do i have to change something in the chart or in my php-output-file?

http://www.abload.de/img/error1234hxudx.jpeg

Greetings!

Comment: I don't know highchart - but couldn't you go through the entire array, check for `0` and change every `0` to `0.0000001` instead?

Comment: Can you provide some of the PHP code you're using to provide the data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide data for the intervals between the two points with values. I do this by creating an array of dates/times all with a value of 0 then merge my data into that array.